# Working with Mongoose fields from a find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

So I've search all around trying to figure this out, and I think I'm just missing something simple..but I can't quite figure it out.

Using Mongoose, I'm finding a specific document and when that document is found, I want to see if the field senderDel is set to true, then I'll do a remove.  If its set to false, I do a update.

Code:

```
PMessage.delete = function(msgId, callback)
{
    Message.find({_id: msgId}, function(e, res){
        if (res){
            console.log(res);
            if (res.senderDel == true){
                console.log("sender deleted...call message remove");
                Message.remove({_id: msgId}, callback);
            } else {
                console.log("res.senderDel is not true");
                Message.findByIdAndUpdate(msgId, {$set: {receiverDel: true}}, callback);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("error: " + e); 
            callback; 
        }
    });
};
```

console.log(res) returns:

```
[ { sender: 50ea4e8198c6770e1e000004,
senderName: 'tester',
receiver: 50ac4ac5bca9f1794b000007,
receiverName: 'admin',
subject: 'a',
body: 'a',
_id: 5101a35a7889727e35000006,
__v: 0,
receiverDel: false,
senderDel: true,
read: false,
sentOn: '01/24/2013 21:10:50' } ]
```

I would have thought that I could reference the senderDel field with res.senderDel?  Why is res.senderDel coming up as undefined, and how can I modify this to make it work?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Adding my schema:

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
    sender: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    senderName: String,
    receiver: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    receiverName: String,
    subject: String,
    body: String,
    sentOn: {type: String, default: moment().format()},
    read: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    senderDel: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    receiverDel: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
```

Comment: Do you have `senderDel` in your [schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)?

Comment: Yes, I do.  I'll edit the post to reflect my schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.find` function returns an array of documents, not a single document. If you want to find a single document, use `model.findOne` or `model.findById`:

```
PMessage.delete = function(msgId, callback)
{
    Message.findById(msgId, function(e, res){
        if (res){
            console.log(res);
            if (res.senderDel == true){
                console.log("sender deleted...call message remove");
                Message.remove({_id: msgId}, callback);
            } else {
                console.log("res.senderDel is not true");
                Message.findByIdAndUpdate(msgId, {$set: {receiverDel: true}}, callback);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("error: " + e); 
            callback; 
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Oh, You're absolutely right!  Using res[0].senderDel fixes it as well.  Thanks for your help, its much appreciated. I'll use your fix =)